# Does Material-ui's sx property generate optimized utility classes similar to tailwindcss?

Tags: html, css, material-ui, vite, mui-x

when using tailwind css, it gets compiled like this:

```html
<div class="font-bold"></div>
<div class="font-bold"></div>
```

compiles to

```css
.font-bold{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

So... when using sx like this:

```html
<Box sx={{ p: 1 }}>One</Box>
<Box sx={{ p: 1 }}>two</Box>
```

does it compile like this:

```css
.css-bkjlsd{
  padding: 4px;
}

.css-fdsfdffd{
  padding: 4px;
}
```

OR like this (utility class that many component connects to. created in order to reduce redundant css):

```css
.css-fdjf{
  padding: 4px;
}
```

// is it generating different classes for same stuff inefficiently or is it efficient like tailwindcss and connects many components to one class to minimize bundle size?
I have been hearing that MUI is heavy so I wanted to hear from experienced developers how to optimize MUI for small bundle size.